# Java decimal bigger than BigDecimal?

Tags: java, arrays, excel, csv, bigdecimal

Here is the problem I am having. I have a CSV file I am reading with 4381 small decimal numbers mostly between -5 and 5. Examples of them are `0.00000822, -0.20929117, -2.204, 4.88490078`.

In my program, written with Java, I am reading the CSV file and adding all 4381 numbers together to get a sum. However, the sum that I am getting is nowhere even close to the correct number. If I add the column of numbers together in Excel using `=SUM(C:C)`, I get `10.77918727`. If I add them together in my program, I get `-933.39114459`. As you can see, the numbers are not even remotely close. I do not know that the value from Excel is correct, but I know there is no way -933 is correct for the data.

The thing is, the numbers do add up correctly if I use a smaller set of numbers from another CSV file, so I am sure my program is doing the addition correctly. Regardless, I have placed the code I am using to add the numbers together below.

Because the numbers add up correctly with a smaller sample, the only thing I can think of that would cause such an incorrect sum to be calculated is I am running out of bits in my `sum` variable (called `gainLoss`). That leads me to my question: is there a way to represent a decimal with more bits in Java than using BigDecimal? I'm already using BigDecimal and it seems to not provide enough bits unless I am doing something wrong.

An idea I had to get around the limitations of BigDecimal would be to manually use scientific notation like BigDecimal does, but I'd use a BigDecimal as the base and a BigDecimal as the scale. The only issue with that is it seems like a lot of work that I'd like to avoid if there's a better way to represent bigger numbers.

Let me know if there is a better way to represent numbers that need a huge number of bits or if I am doing something wrong. I'll take any suggestions as well.

Here is the code I am using to add the numbers together (minus all the checks I have to do to first make sure a number should be added):

```
// gainLoss is the sum of all the numbers
BigDecimal gainLoss = new BigDecimal(0.0);

// data is a 2D Object array of all the data from the CSV file.
// The 2nd column in data is filled with BigDecimal objects
for (int i = 1; i < data.length; i++) // for each data row in data (excluding the header row)
{
    // set rowAmt to the value of the number in the current row of the CSV file
    BigDecimal rowAmt = (BigDecimal)data[i][2];

    // add this row's value to gainLoss
    gainLoss = gainLoss.add(rowAmt);
}
```

Edit: Here is the full code I am using to calculate the sum, as requested:

```
public static BigDecimal calcGainLoss(Object[][] data, Calendar startCal, Calendar endCal)
{
    BigDecimal gainLoss = new BigDecimal("0.0");
    for (int i = 1; i < data.length; i++) // for each data row in data
    {
        int lineNum = i + 1;
        System.out.println("Line " + lineNum + ", i " + i + ":   " + gainLoss.toString());
        // Load the important values into memory
        String rowType = (String)data[i][4];
        BigDecimal rowAmt = (BigDecimal)data[i][2];
        Calendar rowDate = (Calendar)data[i][1];

        // Check if this row should be included in the calculations based on its row type
        if (rowType.equalsIgnoreCase("cancel")) // if this was a cancelled transaction
        {
            continue; // move on to the next row
        }

        // Check if this row should be included in the calculations based on its date
        boolean rowIsIncludedDate = false; // whether this row is within the given date range
        if ((startCal == null) && (endCal == null)) // if no start or end date was given
        {
            rowIsIncludedDate = true;
        }
        else if ((startCal == null) && (!rowDate.after(endCal))) // if no start date was given and the current row's date is before or equal to the end date
        {
            rowIsIncludedDate = true;
        }
        else if ((endCal == null) && (!rowDate.before(startCal))) // if no end date was given and the current row's date is equal to or after the start date
        {
            rowIsIncludedDate = true;
        }
        else if ((!rowDate.before(startCal)) && (!rowDate.after(endCal))) // if both dates were given and the current row's date is equal to or after the start date and equal to or before the end date
        {
            rowIsIncludedDate = true;
        }

        if (!rowIsIncludedDate) // if this row should not be included in the calculation because its date is outside of the requested range
        {
            continue; // go on to the next row
        }

        // Add the current row's value to the current sum
        gainLoss = gainLoss.add(rowAmt);
        System.out.println("Adding " + rowAmt.toString());
    }

    return gainLoss;
}
```

Comment: What did you learn by stepping through your code with a debugger?

Comment: I actually never tried that. I'll do that now.

Comment: Or by inserting printouts so you could watch the process as it runs?

(Are you sure you've actually populated data[][] correctly?)

Comment: Yeah, @keshlam's idea is probably better.  You don't really want to sit there "stepping through" 4381 loop iterations.

Comment: I am sure I have populated data[][] correctly. I ran tests with printouts right after I finished writing the code to load data[][].

Comment: Print out the first 20 numbers and the "running sum" - do they make sense? When does it go wrong?

Comment: You may have one or more numbers in your input file which are parsed incorrectly. Either a number is read to be larger than it is or the parse code reads two or more numbers which should only be one number and the one or more fragments mistaken for a number is read simply as a large integer. A debugger is one approach. Another is to add print statements to your loop to print the sum and the most recent addend when the sum changes by more than, say, ten. Increase or decrease the threshold value from ten as needed until you catch something in the net or are confident the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: And since you have the numbers in Excel, try sorting the numbers (easy). Then copy the array, paste in the next column, and sort in reverse order (easy). Then add a third column in which you add the two columns together, element by element. Finally take the sum of that third column. The result should be twice the correct answer. Does it come even close?

Comment: I just re-read your question and I am now really worried about the line "(minus all the checks I have to do to first make sure a number should be added)" . I think you need to show those checks. I suspect that your problem is in the code you don't show...

Comment: I printed out each number and sum in my 'adding' loop and it looks like the number gets progressively bigger in the negative direction overall. It doesn't suddenly become incorrect. I also checked a few of the additions in the printouts to make sure they looked correct and they did. That tells me the error is probably not caused by running out of bits.

Comment: I have added the full code that I am using to find the sum, as requested.

Comment: Could it be that there are numbers in column C in excel that should not be included in the sum? You are doing `SUM(C:C)` which goes all the way to the bottom of the spreadsheet. What if you did `SUM(C1:C4381)` instead?

Comment: What is the equivalent in Excel for excluding certain rows based on dates?

Comment: `=SUM(C1:C4381)` gives the same result as `=SUM(C:C)`. Good idea, though. By the way, I cannot easily sort the data because Excel saves the data I need in a different format than when it reads the CSV. It basically only saves the date and doesn't save the times that are in the same column as the dates. I need both the dates and times for the program to be able to read the CSV properly.

Comment: I suspect your problem is with the dates / times. I repeat my question: how do you exclude certain rows in Excel that don't meet your date criteria? And - converting the date/time to a properly formatted string before saving as CSV ought to allow you to preserve all relevant information.

Comment: I am not excluding any rows by date in the program or Excel at this time. I'm currently just sending `null` to the method for the 2 dates. The only rows that are getting excluded in the program and not in Excel are the rows that have the `cancel` tag on them. If someone could give me a formula that would exclude any rows with `cancel` in the 5th column in Excel from the sum, I'll use that to get a real value in Excel. I'll also look it up in the meantime.

Comment: You want to use `SUM(C1:C4381) - SUMIF(E1:E4381, "cancel", C1:C4381)` - basically, sum all elements, then subtract all the ones that had "cancel" in column E. Adapt as needed.

Comment: Well... dang. Excel gave me `-933.3911446` with that formula. I guess my program is adding correctly (assuming Excel also is, which is usually the case). My problem must lie in the data itself or the way I process it.

Comment: And if I remove the part of my code that filters out the `cancel` rows, I get `10.77918727`, just like Excel was giving me with my old `=SUM(C:C)` formula. I'm looking closely at the data and it seems that `cancel` does not mean what my employer (the one sending me CSV files) told me it means. I'll have to figure that out with him. Thanks for all the help though, guys! I am supposed to pick a correct answer to the question, right? I'm not sure what to do since it turned out my data source was incorrect (or at least it seems that way).

Comment: I have updated my answer to account for the things we have discovered, making it an "acceptable" answer, I believe.

Comment: I have made your answer the correct answer. You definitely helped me the most, and the answer covers most of the important topics we went through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a long shot, but sometimes if numbers are of very different magnitude you can run into a problem like this. The solution is to sort the numbers first, then take the difference between large pairs first.  Example of how you would run into trouble:

```
10E38 + 5 - 10E38
```

will return 0 instead of 5. But

```
10E38 - 10E38 + 5
```

will return 5 (when evaluated from left to right). You don't "lose the 5" by adding it to the 10E38 (there would not be enough bits to store that) when you do things in the correct order.

It is quite unusual that "real world data" gives rise to rounding errors as big as you are experiencing, though. It is possible that you are interpreting the Excel data the wrong way. Since you have now clarified that you are not adding certain numbers when another column contains the word "cancel", you might want to confirm that you are, in fact, getting a different answer than Excel by computing the following formula:

```
=SUM(C1:C4381) - SUMIF(E1:E4381, "cancel", C1:C4381)
```

- basically, this says "sum all elements, then subtract the ones with 'cancel' next to them".

It may turn out that your code is correct, and your assumption about the answer (or the data) is wrong...

Comment: That shouldn't happen with `BigDecimal`, because it just takes up as many bits as it needs.  Of course, this depends on how the numbers are finding their way _into_ the `data[][]` array - maybe OP is converting them to `double` before they become `BigDecimal`, or something like that.

Comment: Yes - as I said "it is a long shot". But as OP says he is sure the numbers in the array are correct you have to wonder...

Comment: This answer highlights one example of problems which can arise when summing a large number of floating-point numbers. One very good solution is the [Kahan summation algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm).

Comment: @NedNowotny thanks for pointing to that algorithm; I had not come across it.

Comment: I would like to add that anyone seeing this in the future should look at the comment thread under the main question as well as this answer.

Comment: Anyone care to speculate why someone marked this answer as "not useful"? It describes the general problem of summing large numbers, including a solution - and goes on to give information on how to check that the Excel formula (the supposed "ground truth") is giving the right answer. Clearly it helped the person asking the question...